# Print matrixes on two rows

Tags: matrices

I am trying to print my matrixes on two rows. This is my code:

```
$ D^{(0)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 8 & \infty & -4 \\
\infty & 0 & \infty & 1 & 7 \\
\infty & 4 & 0 & \infty &\infty \\
2 & \infty & -5 & 0 & \infty \\
\infty &\infty &\infty &6 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

$ D^{(1)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & 8         & \infty    & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7         \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & \infty    &\infty     \\
2   & 5     & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

$ D^{(2)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & 8         & 4     & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7         \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & 5     & 11        \\
2   & 5     & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

$ D^{(3)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & 8         & 4     & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7         \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & 5     & 11        \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

$ D^{(4)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & -1        & 4     & -4        \\
3    & 0        & -4        & 1         & -1        \\
7    & 4        & 0         & 5     & 3     \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
8    & 5        & 1         & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

$ D^{(5)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 1     & -3        & 2     & -4        \\
3    & 0        & -4        & 1         & -1        \\
7    & 4        & 0         & 5     & 3     \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
8    & 5        & 1         & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix} $
```

(sorry, on my editor everything looked better)

Now, it displays them like this:

```
D0
D1
D2
D3
D4
D5
```

(without spaces between one and the other)

But I would like to see them like this:

```
D0    D1    D2
D3    D4    D5
```

(or at least add spaces between one and another)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blank lines in TeX and LaTeX documents cause paragraph breaks.

I suggest you use an `align*` environment. Optionally, use `bmatrix*` environments instead of `bmatrix` environments to right-align the matrices' columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 &D^{(0)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0 & 3 & 8 & \infty & -4 \\
\infty & 0 & \infty & 1 & 7 \\
\infty & 4 & 0 & \infty &\infty \\
2 & \infty & -5 & 0 & \infty \\
\infty &\infty &\infty &6 & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\quad
 &&D^{(1)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0   & 3     & 8         & \infty    & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7         \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & \infty    &\infty     \\
2   & 5     & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\quad
 &&D^{(2)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0   & 3     & 8         & 4     & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7         \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & 5     & 11        \\
2   & 5     & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\\[2ex] % add a bit of vertical whitespace
 &D^{(3)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0   & 3     & 8         & 4     & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7         \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & 5     & 11        \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\quad
 &&D^{(4)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0   & 3     & -1        & \phantom{-}4     & -4        \\
3    & 0        & -4        & 1         & -1        \\
7    & 4        & 0         & 5     & 3     \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
8    & 5        & 1         & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\quad
 &&D^{(5)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0   & 1     & -3        & 2     & -4        \\
3    & 0        & -4        & 1         & -1        \\
7    & 4        & 0         & 5     & 3     \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2         \\ 
8    & 5        & 1         & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request to display just two matrices per row, and hence to typeset the matrices across 3 rows rather than just 2. I also implemented @egreg's suggestion not to use `bmatrix*` environments for the first four matrices, which contain `\infty` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page paramters
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 &D^{(0)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0      & 3      & 8      & \infty & -4     \\
\infty & 0      & \infty & 1      & 7      \\
\infty & 4      & 0      & \infty &\infty  \\
2      & \infty & -5     & 0      & \infty \\
\infty & \infty & \infty & 6      & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\quad
 &&D^{(1)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0      & 3      & 8      & \infty & -4    \\
\infty & 0      & \infty & 1      & 7     \\
\infty & 4      & 0      & \infty &\infty \\
2      & 5      & -5     & 0      & -2    \\ 
\infty & \infty & \infty & 6      & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\\[2ex]
 &D^{(2)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0      & 3      & 8      & 4 & -4  \\
\infty & 0      & \infty & 1 & 7   \\
\infty & 4      & 0      & 5 & 11  \\
2      & 5      & -5     & 0 & -2  \\ 
\infty & \infty & \infty & 6 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\quad
 &&D^{(3)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0      & 3      & 8      & 4 & -4  \\
\infty & 0      & \infty & 1 & 7   \\
\infty & 4      & 0      & 5 & 11  \\
2      & -1     & -5     & 0 & -2  \\ 
\infty & \infty & \infty & 6 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\\[2ex]
 &D^{(4)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0 & 3  & -1  & \phantom{-}4 & -4 \\
3 & 0  & -4  & 1 & -1 \\
7 & 4  & 0   & 5 & 3  \\
2 & -1 & -5  & 0 & -2 \\ 
8 & 5  & 1   & 6 & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\quad
 &&D^{(5)} = 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0 & 1  & -3 & \phantom{-}2 & -4 \\
3 & 0  & -4 & 1 & -1 \\
7 & 4  & 0  & 5 & 3  \\
2 & -1 & -5 & 0 & -2 \\ 
8 & 5  & 1  & 6 & 0
\end{bmatrix*} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `matrix*` can do for matrices with only numbers. With infinity the result is not what I'd like to see.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: I accidentaly deleted my comment... Thank you very much also for the second output!!!

Comment: @hellomynameisA - You're most welcome!

Comment: @egreg - Please see the addendum I posted in response to a (since-deleted) follow-up request by the OP. I took that opportunity to implement your suggestion, i.e., to use `bmatrix` rather than `bmatrix*` environments for the first four matrices, all of which contain `\infty` symbols.

Comment: @Mico I'd not mix the two types in the same display, but +1 anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `align` blocks:  `y &= x     &     y &= x    &    y &= x`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
D^{(0)} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 8 & \infty & -4 \\
\infty & 0 & \infty & 1 & 7 \\
\infty & 4 & 0 & \infty &\infty \\
2 & \infty & -5 & 0 & \infty \\
\infty &\infty &\infty &6 & 0
\end{bmatrix}                        
&% new block
D^{(1)} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & 8         & \infty    & -4        \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7     \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & \infty    &\infty \\
2   & 5     & -5        & 0         & -2        \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix}                        
&% new block
D^{(2)} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & 8         & 4     & -4            \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7     \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & 5     & 11        \\
2   & 5     & -5        & 0         & -2        \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix}  \\[\medskipamount] 
D^{(3)} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & 8         & 4     & -4           \\
\infty & 0      & \infty    & 1         & 7    \\
\infty & 4      & 0         & 5     & 11       \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2   \\ 
\infty & \infty     & \infty    & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix}   
&% new block
D^{(4)} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0   & 3     & -1        & \phantom{-}4     & -4 \\
3    & 0        & -4        & 1         & -1    \\
7    & 4        & 0         & 5     & 3         \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2    \\ 
8    & 5        & 1         & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix}  
&% new block
D^{(5)} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0   & 1     & -3        & 2     & -4            \\
3    & 0        & -4        & 1         & -1    \\
7    & 4        & 0         & 5     & 3         \\
2   & -1        & -5        & 0         & -2    \\ 
8    & 5        & 1         & 6         & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd get rid of the `\phantom{-}` directive in `D^{4}`.